# python 3.7 setting environment variable path

Tags: python-3.x, path, environment-variables

I installed Anaconda 3 and wanted to execute python from the shell. It returned that it's either written wrong or does not exist. Apparently, I have to add a path to the environmentle variable.

Can someone tell how to do this?

Environment: Windows 10, 64 bit and python 3.7

Ps: I know the web is full with that but I am notoriously afraid to make a mistake. And I did not find an exact entry for my environment. Thanks in advance.

Best Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows:**

- search for -->Edit the system environment variables
- In Advanced tab, click Environment variabless
- In System variables, Select PATH and click edit. Now Click new, ADD YOU PATH.
- Click Apply and close.

Now, check in command prompt

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I installed Anaconda 3. So, is the correct path "C:\Users\<myname>\Anaconda3" ? If it is, it did not work out :(.

Comment: @Daniel2805- Edited my answer. Can please check third point again and try. And delete the path which was are created previously.

Comment: Now it works, I just moved it to the second position in the list.